# How to confirm if motherboard is still fine

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard, desktop

My Asus ROG G20CI keeps booting into the BIOS. I have unplugged all USB devices (other than the mouse), but it still doesn't boot into Windows.

I took the unit to the shop, the guys said they tried to boot it up and it had the same issue. They said they tried to network boot too, but it didn't work, saying that it might be a motherboard issue.

I wasn't convinced, I took apart the unit and removed the SSD, plugged the SSD into another computer, and the SSD was inaccessible. This got me thinking that it's an issue with the SSD and the rest of the unit is fine, but how can I confirm this before investing in a new SSD?

When I put another HDD in the unit it states "BIOS in this system is not fully ACPI compliant" but because the HDD is from another working computer, I don't want to format it.

I'm planning to get an new SSD, but don't want to do it just to find out that the motherboard is faulty. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have concerns with both your motherboard and SSD i would [make a Linux Live USB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). If you can boot Linux from the USB its unlikely your motherboard is causing your Windows booting issues. You can use tools in Linux to test your hard drive if you decide to go this route.